# Sublime Text 2 BracketHighlighter for Django Template Syntax

Tags: django, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

I'd like BracketHighlighter to highlight my django template brackets {% %} and {{ }}.

I've made the following edits to User/bh_core.sublime-settings:

```
"user_brackets": [
    {
        "name": "django",
        "open": "(\\{\\%)",
        "close": "(\\%\\})",
        "style": "django",
        "scope_exclude": ["string", "comment"],
        "scope_exclude_exceptions": ["text.tex string.other.math"],
        "language_filter": "blacklist",
        "language_list": ["Plain text", "Hex"],
        "find_in_sub_search": "true",
        "ignore_string_escape": true,
        "enabled": true
    }
```

]

but it doesn't seem to work (even after restarting ST2). I've tried using "user_scope_brackets" as well, with no luck. Anyone know of a solution?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "auto-pair"? BracketHighlighter just highlights brackets, it doesn't have anything to do with, for example, typing in `{%` and having `%}` automatically appear.

Comment: I must've misunderstood that there was bracket auto-completion. I'd still like to highlight `{%` and `%}` if that's possible though. Let me update the question.

Comment: Update: I ended up not using BracketHighlighter. Instead, I grabbed a .tmLanguage file from https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=932 that has django template syntax highlighting. Put the file in 'Packages/Django' and switched the sublime syntax in 'view > syntax'

Answer (score -2):

Install a package which supports the Django template editing through the package manager.

Check the link below for understanding how to install and proceed with package manager

https://packagecontrol.io/

Comment: What basically happened here is the question "I'd like a chair that's more comfortable." was asked, and you gave an answer like "You should just go buy a new standing desk, here's the store I shop at."